# Plugin/ native way to remotely edit files (ssh, sftp, ...) in Atom?

Tags: ssh, ftp, sftp, atom-editor

Is there a plugin or a native way to remotely edit files (ssh, sftp, ...) in Atom, that's similar to the native one in Coda 2? I need something simple just like in Coda, without the need to setup anything except a project and connection details maybe. And also be able to browser the remote files in the same file tree you browse the local ones?

Comment: I've spent the last 2 days playing with all the SFTP packages and they all fall short. Whoever makes something like ST3's SFTP will be a hero.

Comment: Maybe this isnt "simple", but what I do is use [sshfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS) to mount the remote filesystem as if it were a local folder, and then just open the project folder in atom.